# How to use jQuery code in window's scope when jQuery is asynced

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a simplified version of the code we're using. The aim is to have jQuery load in async, and be able to use jQuery references in the doSomething() function. If the doSomething() function is coded inside the "onload" function, it's no longer in the window's scope, and the "A" link fails.

However if the doSomething() function is coded inside the main doc, jQuery may or may not load before DomContentLoaded.

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething()">Do it</a>

<script>
function doSomething(){
    $("#aaaa").fadeIn( "slow", function(){});
}
</script>

<script src="jquery.js" async id="jQ"></script>

<script>
document.getElementById("jQ").onload = function(){
    doSomething();
}
</script>
```

Thanks @skobaljic and @vitkarpov, your solutions worked.

New working code:

```
<span id="cob1" data-action="args1">Do it</span>
<span id="cob2" data-action="args2">Do it again</span>

<script src="jquery.js" async id="jQ"></script>

<script>
document.getElementById("jQ").onload = function(){
    $("#cob1,#cob2").click(function(a){
        a = $(this).attr('data-action');

        $("#" + a).fadeIn( "slow", function(){});
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's the reason why you should not encode JS into your html first way. Make it `<a data-action="doSomething" ... >` instead, than assign events after jQuery loaded.

Comment: I'd suggest the same as @skobaljic did. Moreover, the link should be better disabled and gets back to normal when JavaScript is ready.